# Laravel/artisan can not find "node" in puphpeteer package

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, composer-php, puppeteer

I'm working on using [puphpeteer](https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer), which is a PHP wrapper for the original puppeteer functionality, to do some automated downloads from a website. I've followed the instructions as they were written in the documentation and tried to create an object:

```
public function getReport(){
    $puppeteer = new Puppeteer;
}
```

Simply instantiating the object above produces the following error:

```
Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\username\Projects\projectfolder\public 

Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 

node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I did find that the object is just failing to be instantiated in the __constructor(). I can follow the stack trace of the code but none of it is helping me understand what is going wrong, which is that Laravel/artisan do not see node as a valid command.

General notes:

- PHP 7.3.9
- Laravel 7.1.3
- Composer 1.9.0
- node v12.16.1
- node is in my path as the first variable
- using Windows 10

How do I get Laravel/artisan to recognize that I have a node installation for this package?

Comment: how are you running the laravel app? Are you running it in Homestead or some other VM etc? If so, are the apps you're talking about above (specifically node) installed in that virtual machine?

Comment: to be 1000% clear right now, I'm trying to do development work, so I'm running the server via "php artisan serve" (I also am not a Laravel expert; I am much more comfortable in other languages, but alas here we are)

Comment: Ah, that may be why, Im not 100% sure what exactly artisan serve does but its not a real web server and may not have access to the apps on your machine like that. Id recommend developing with [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead). It only takes a few minutes to get it going and everything is set up perfectly for developing a Laravel app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the location of node on your system? Try placing it here:

```
$puppeteer = new Puppeteer([
    'executable_path' => "PATH_TO_NODE_HERE"
]);
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying asap, this was a side project that was a "nice to have" so it's taken a backburner. I'll note your response and return when I return to the project; thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem with Laravel/Artisan.
`'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`
after adding

```
$puppeteer = new Puppeteer([
    'executable_path' => "PATH_TO_NODE_HERE"
]);
```

Puppeteer generate socket error so I move my project to wamp instead of Laravel/Artisan. 
all working fine with out adding 'executable_path' on wamp. better to move your project to Wamp or Xampp server. you can read nesk comment here
`https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer/issues/35`